# Why is HTML not being rendered inside body in IE9?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, validation, debugging

I am facing a huge problem at the moment.

I have built a site in wordpress and on all other browsers its great but on IE all I see is the body rendered on screen and any other elements inside just do not appear so I get a blank screen with just the  background image and nothing in between.

Further more when I view source in IE9/IE8 tools it shows up. Here is the url: http://shiftms.staging.wpengine.com/

I have validated the html and all is fine so I am a bit confused as to why its not working.

Has anyone ever faced this before?

Thanks

Comment: Can you try removing `<div class="clearfix" id="page">` this div

Comment: Do you think this could be the issue?

Comment: That did not seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The F12 developer tools show that the other sections, such as the header are not even in the DOM. That could be because the HTML does not validate. In particular, there is a `<button type="search" class="fa fa-search 3d-submit" />` which is invalid. `<button>` is not selfclosing. You need a `<button>...</button>` instead.